# Does PHP's virtual() function save server memory?

Tags: php, download

We have sensitive files on a server. We want these to be accessible only to logged in users, so we serve them through a PHP script which checks whether the user has permission to view these files. Then we serve the file with `readfile()`.

This works fine, but it's my understanding that `readfile()` will load the entire file into memory, and then serve it, while `virtual()` will serve it directly from PHP, and thus reduce the stress on the server's memory. `readfile()` is working fine for now, but a new client wants the same functionality with much larger files, and I was wondering whether moving to `virtual()` would be better.

1. Is my understanding of `readfile()` and `virtual()` correct?
2. Are there any gotchas with, for example, caching? Or anything else I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. `virtual()` will make PHP use less memory, but Apache will issue one extra request.

A better way would be the Apache X-Sendfile module. All you'd need to do from PHP is an extra `header()` call and Apache will serve the file for you, instead of PHP. That uses even less resources.

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.jasny.net/articles/how-i-php-x-sendfile)

Comment: Yeah, use Apache X-Sendfile or if you are on nginx X-Accel-Redirect http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile

Comment: Found link at http://www.jasny.net/articles/how-i-php-x-sendfile. I tried to edit this into your answer, but was told that edits must be more than six characters.

Comment: lighttpd also has X-Sendfile support